# What's wrong here? Trying to write results of this function into file

Tags: python

```
def pryklad (b):
    a=1 
    while a < 10:
        print a*b
        a=a+1

if __name__=="__main__":
    pryklad(3)
    a=pryklad(3)
    value=str(a)
    file=open('C:/Python27/file.txt','w+')
    file.write(value)
    print file
```

Comment: I think there is a lack in programming skills rather than in Python. I suggest to write comments to your code so that you can understand program flows. E.g. what you think the first call to 'pryklad' will do? and the second?

Answer (score 2):

`a = pryklad(3)` results in `a` being `None`, because you don't have a `return` statement in your function. Now it simply prints some numbers. Also, I'm not sure what you suppose to get from `print file`.

Answer (score 2):

Many things are wrong in your program

1. pryklad() function is not returning any value.
2. You are not storing value of first call to pryklad() function.
3. You don't have to convert value returned by pryklad() to string using str().
4. Last line `print file` won't print actual contents of the file. It
   will print some information about `file` object.
5. Lastly, this is actually not an error but try to follow some good
   coding standards like giving proper names to functions (at least I
   am not able to understand meaning of pryklad, maybe other people
   know meaning of it),

   giving proper names to variables instead of
   `a`, `b` use variables names like `height`, `weight` (its a wild
   guess but I am assuming that you are trying to measure area of
   rectangle)

Try these things and then you will be able to view some values in your file.txt

Comment: On point 3: if the code was working correctly, I think the OP would actually have to convert the value to a string before writing it to the file.

Answer (score 1):

If a python does not `return` anything specifically, it will return `None`.

Your function, instead of returning `a*b` every loop, *prints* it. The function never returns anything, so it returns `None`.

Thus when you do `a = pryklad(3)`, `a is None`. And so you're then writing `"None"` to your file.

---

You might want `yield` here. This will return the value `a*b` but the function won't break. Then, in your `if __name__=="__main__":` code block, change `a=pryklad(3)` to `a=list(pryklad(3))`. `a` will contain a list of `a*b` for each loop in the while loop.

Then you might want to add each number into the file. Here, use a `with` statement:

```
with open('C:/Python27/file.txt','w+') as myfile:
    for number in a:
        myfile.write(str(number))
```

If you then want to print the contents of the file, `print file` won't do that. You have to open the file in reading mode again:

```
with open('C:/Python27/file.txt','w+') as myfile:
    print myfile.read()
```